# Why I can't change the font size of plot title and axis title?

Tags: r, plot, title

I can not change the font, font size of axis title and plot title in this case. 
[image]

```
plot(seoul032801_var, cex = 1.5, pch= 16, col = "black",xlab="Distance (Km)", ylab = ~ "Semivariance ( " *( mu * g / m^3)^2 * ")", main=" Semivariogram for 032801", font.main = 1, cex.lab = 2)
```

Here, I am changing cex.lab or font.main but they are not changing! In this case, I want the title of the plot is in plane aerial font and axis title need to be little bit larger.

Also, in the plot I can see some scale marking on upper and right side. Is it possible to remove this marking?

[This is my dataset. You can check.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByY3OAw62EShfkFtUl9yaDB2WjdWSGYzZFZjR0t5RFVheV9ENEtGQnBzZGd4Q2N6dkI3T28)
This is my R code: [You can check the last line of my code]

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)
library(automap)
library(rgdal)
library(e1071)

seoul032801 <- read.csv("seoul032801.csv")
seoul032801<-na.omit(seoul032801)

coordinates(seoul032801) <- ~LON+LAT
proj4string(seoul032801) =  "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" 
seoul032801<-spTransform(seoul032801, 
                         CRS("+proj=utm +north +zone=52 +datum=WGS84"))
seoul032801@coords<- seoul032801@coords/1000

#variogram modeling
seoul032801_var<-variogram(PM10 ~1, data=seoul032801, width = 2.8, cutoff =33)
seoul032801_var
plot(seoul032801_var, cex = 1.5, pch= 16, col = "black",xlab="Distance (Km)", ylab = ~ "Semivariance ( " *( mu * g / m^3)^2 * ")",
     main=" Semivariogram for 032801", font.main = 1, cex.lab = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out `?plot.gstatVariogram` - it plots a lattice plot. Things work a little different:

```
library(gstat)
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
v <- variogram(log(zinc)~1, meuse)
plot(v, xlab=list(cex=2, font=2), main=list(font=4, cex=5, label="foo"))
```

Comment: "Also, in my plot I can see some scale marking on upper and right side. Is it possible to remove this marking?"

Is it possible? Or is this format okay in scientific paper?

Comment: Looks good to me. But it should also be possible to remove them if you want. Please consult the lattice parameters.